# Spliting up long linq queries for improved maintainability

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring

I have a bunch of these Tasks that are all based on LINQ queries. I am looking for good way to refactor them and make them easier to read and allow me to change the queries depending on language/region etc.

```
var mailTaskOne = CreateTask(() => myService.Mail.Where(p => p.ProjectName == "Delta"
    && (p.MailLang== (int)MailLanguage.EU || p.MailLang == (int)MailLanguage.RU)
    && (p.DateEntered >= startDate && p.DateEntered <= endDate)
    && p.MailPriority == (int)MailPriority.High).Count());
```

One of the ways I thought would be convenient would be to split the query up into something like this.

```
var results = myService.Mail.Where(x => x.ProjectName == "Delta");
results = results.Where(p => p.MailLang== (int)MailLanguage.EU);
results = results.Where(p => p.DateModified >= startDate && p.DateModified <= endDate);
```

This would allow me to do this without having to repeat the whole query for each region.

```
if (MailLanguage == "English")
    results = results.Where(p => p.MailLang== (int)MailLanguage.EU);
else
    results = results.Where(p => p.MailLang== (int)MailLanguage.RU);
```

Is there anyone that knows a better solution for this? I end up having huge functions as I need to do maybe 20 of these queries depending on the requirements; such as Region, Project name etc.

---

**Edit:**

Due to some limitations I did not know of with the back-end (web service/api) I could unfortunately not use some of the awesome answers mentioned in this question.

For example this does not get translated properly, but in no ways because the answer incorrect, simply does not work with the API I am working against -- possibly because it is poorly implemented.

```
public bool IsValid(Type x)
{
    return (x.a == b) && (x.c ==d) && (x.d == e);
}
```

Anyway, anyone looking for similar solutions all of these are valid answers, but in the end I ended up going with something similar to the solution snurre provided.

Comment: Why don't you use language as a parameter/variable?

Comment: Feel free to explain further - my mind is at a blank at the moment. Keep in mind that there might be multiple languages, as for example English might for example be US + EU. :]

Comment: Are you querying on database or memory?

Comment: It is a database. So these are all `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a parameter class like:

```
public class MailParameters
{
    public DateTime EndTime { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> Languages { get; private set; }
    public int Priority { get; private set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; private set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; private set; }

    public MailParameters(string projectName, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, MailLang language, Priority priority)
        : this(projectName, startTime, endTime, new[] { language }, priority)

    public MailParameters(string projectName, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, IEnumerable<MailLang> languages, Priority priority)
    {
        ProjectName = projectName;
        StartTime = startTime;
        EndTime = endTime;
        Languages = languages.Cast<int>();
        Priority = (int)priority;
    }
}
```

Then add these extension methods:

```
public static int Count(this IQueryable<Mail> mails, MailCountParameter p)
{
    return mails.Count(m =>
        m.ProjectName == p.ProjectName &&
        p.Languages.Contains(m.MailLang) &&
        m.EnteredBetween(p.StartTime, p.EndTime) &&
        m.Priority == p.Priority);
}

public static bool EnteredBetween(this Mail mail, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
    return mail.DateEntered >= startTime && mail.DateEntered <= endTime;
}
```

The usage would then be:

```
var mailParametersOne = new MailParameters("Delta", startDate, endDate, new[] { MailLang.EU, MailLang.RU }, MailPriority.High);
var mailTaskOne = CreateTask(() => myService.Mail.Count(mailParametersOne));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with just splitting up the query onto different lines like you suggested, it means you can put comments per line to describe what it is doing. You are still only making 1 trip to the database so you aren't losing anything in terms of performance but gaining better readability.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so myself, but wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing anything obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply have a method for the purpose?

```
public static IQueryable<Mail> Count(this IQueryable<Mail> mails, 
                  string projectName, 
                  MailLanguage mailLanguage,
                  DateTime startDate,
                  DateTime endDate) {
    return mails.Count(p=>
           p.ProjectName == projectName
           && p.MailLang == mailLanguage
           && p.DateEntered >= startDate 
           && p.DateEntered <= endDate
           && p.MailPriority == (int)MailPriority.High);
}
```

then you can simply use it like this

```
CreateTask(() => myService.Mail.Count("Delta",MailLanguage.EU,startDate,endDate));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could turn project name, data modified, mail language and any other criteria into variables and guive them the value you want based on any condition. Then your query would use the variables not the literal values.

```
var projectName="Delta";
var mailLanguage=(int)MailLanguage.RU;

var results=myService.Mail.Where(x => x.ProjectName == projectName)
            && (p.MailLang== mailLanguage);
```

That way you can put most of the complexity in giving the values to the variables and the linq query would be easier to read and mantain.

Answer (score 1):

Consider moving the complex comparisons into a function. For exanple, instead of

```
Results.Where(x => (x.a == b) && (x.c == d) && (x.d == e))
```

consider

```
Results.Where(x => IsValid(x))

...

public bool IsValid(Type x)
{
    return (x.a == b) && (x.c ==d) && (x.d == e);
}
```

The code becomes more readable and IsValid is easy to test using an automated testing framework.

Comment: An even more readable version would be: Results.Where(IsValid)

Comment: Thanks! You guys aren't exactly making it easy to choose a correct answer with so many good ones! :D

Comment: If you're going to use your own functions/methods inside queries, be careful about only running this on local object queries. Inserted midway through a database-facing query, this could either force the rest of the query to be done locally and drag half the database down in memory to facilitate this, or it could just blow up at runtime as the LINQ provider can't figure out how to translate this. (Of course, just using a method to construct an IQueryable with the additional filtering is fine and what you're after.)

Answer (score 0):

My final solution is based on an article by ScottGu.
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

I build the LINQ query like this.

```
    var linqStatements = new List<String>();

    linqStatements.Add(parser.StringToLinqQuery<Project>("ProjectId", report.Project));
    linqStatements.Add(parser.StringToLinqQuery<Region>("RegionId", report.Region));
    linqStatements.Add(parser.StringToLinqQuery<Status>("Status", report.Status));
    linqStatements.Add(parser.StringToLinqQuery<Priority>("Priority", report.Priority));
    linqStatements.Add(parser.StringToLinqQuery<Category>("CategoryId", report.Category));
    linqStatements.Add(AccountIdsToLinqQuery(report.PrimaryAssignment));

    string baseQuery = String.Join(" AND ", linqStatements.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)));
    var linqQuery = service.Mail.Where(baseQuery).Cast<Mail>();
```

The `StringToLinqQuery` looks something like this (simplified version).

```
public string StringToLinqQuery<TEnum>(string field, string value) where TEnum : struct
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        return String.Empty;

    var valueArray = value.Split('|');
    var query = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < valueArray.Count(); i++)
    {
        TEnum result;
        if (Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(valueArray[i].ToLower(), true, out result))
        {
            if (i > 0)
                query.Append(" OR ");
            query.AppendFormat("{0} == {1}", field, Convert.ToInt32(result));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new DynoException("Item '" + valueArray[i] + "' not found. (" + type of (TEnum) + ")",
                                    query.ToString());
        }
    }

    // Wrap field == value with parentheses ()
    query.Insert(0, "(");
    query.Insert(query.Length, ")");

    return query.ToString();
}
```

And the end result would look something like this.

```
service.Mail.Where("(ProjectId == 5) AND (RegionId == 6 OR RegionId == 7) AND (Status == 5) and (Priority == 5)")
```

In my project I store the values in an XML file, and then feed them into the above LINQ query. If an field is empty it will be ignored. It also support multiple values using the `|` sign, e.g. `EU|US` would translate to `(Region == 5 OR Region == 6)`.