# Dynamically build LINQ filter for the Any() method?

Tags: linq, dynamic, filter

Any() takes in a Func
how can I dynamically build up filters to it? ie:

```cs
var filter = () a=> a.Text == "ok";//add the first filter
if (flag)
    filter += () a=> a.ID == 5;//add the second filter << obviously this doesn't work.

list.Any(filter);
```

I've also seen code out there to combine a list of Expression> , but i'm not getting that to work because I don't know how to convert it toFunc

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this question I asked can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244208/spliting-up-long-linq-queries-for-improved-maintainability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compose filters by calling other filters from your current one, like this:

```
var input = new[] {"quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps"};
Func<string,bool> filter1 = a => a == "quick";
Func<string,bool> filter2 = a => filter1(a) || a.Length == 3;
foreach (var s in input.Where(filter2)) {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

This prints

```
quick
fox
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/f7sw4G).

You can use the same approach for any predicate-based functions of LINQ, including `Any`:

```
if (input.Any(filter2)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple filter in `Any` like this.

```
list.Any(a=>a.Text == "ok" && a.ID == 5);
```

Comment: I needed multiple filters. I'll update my original post to include different expressions

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `IEnumerable<Func<T,bool>>` then query it e.g.

```
Func<int,bool> isGreaterThanEight = x => x > 8;
Func<int,bool> isEven = x => x % 2 == 0;
Func<int,bool> hasFactorFive = x => x % 5 == 0;

IEnumerable<Func<int,bool>> rules = new List<Func<int,bool>>() 
    { isGreaterThanEight, isEven, hasFactorFive };

var nums = Enumerable.Range(1,10);

var actual = nums.Where( x => rules.Any( r => r(x) ) );

Assert.That( actual, Is.EqualTo( new[]{2,4,5,6,8,9,10} ) );
```